# How to display input boxes in a table from renderUI in R Shiny?

Tags: r, user-interface, input, shiny, user-input

Right now all of the numeric input boxes from uiOutput("prefs") are displaying underneath eachother.
I would like to have them displayed in more of a table like organization such that some are displayed beside eachother and underneath eachother. I cannot figure out how to do this.
Thanks

UI

```
numericInput("inp1","Enter number of treatments:",min=1,3),
numericInput("numoc", "Enter number of outcomes:",min=1,3),
uiOutput("prefs")
```

Server

```
option_vector<-c()

output$prefs <- renderUI({

        k= rep(c(1:input$numoc), times = input$inp1)
        for (g in 1:input$numoc) {
            option_vector<-append(option_vector, g)
        }

        mylist2 <- lapply(1:(input$numoc), function(i,y=k[[i]]) {

            pref_identifier <- paste("rank", i, sep="")
            pref_name<- paste("Outcome #",y,sep="")

            list(
                selectInput(pref_identifier,pref_name, option_vector)
            )
        })

        do.call(tagList, unlist(mylist2, recursive = FALSE))
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do that. Fluid layouts should be the simplest way. It provides a 12 column layout. If you enclose each input control into a column with a width of 6 you get 2 of the in each row. If you want 3 you reduce the width from 6 to 4.

The advantage of this solution is that it adapts to the available width. If the screen is narrow, the UI elements will be shown one below the other. As soon as there is enough space, the layout changes to a matrix layout.

Replace the last two statements (`list` and `do.call`) in your `renderUI` call with this:

```
    fluidRow(
      lapply(mylist2, function(x) column(6L, x))
    )
```

**Solution 2** is the `shinyMatrix` package. With this you do not need to define each ui element. Call the function `shinyMatrix` to create the complete matrix with one call, e.g.

```
matrixInput("myMatrix",
  value = diag(3),
  rows = list(names = FALSE), cols = list(names = FALSE),
  copy = TRUE, paste = TRUE
)
```

gives you a 3x3 matrix of inputs.